# replace can't find % string literals

Tags: python, html

Probably a very basic question, but the following code fails to replace!

```
h = '%3c'
c = '<'
s = 'blah %3c blah'
s.replace(h,c)
print(s)
```

The result is `'blah %3c blah'`.

How do I make replace treat `%3c` as a normal string.

For context, I am HTML encoding and decoding strings by replacing unsafe characters with their %hex representation. I would greatly prefer to use a library for this but haven't been able to find one. As well as answering the above question, the name of such a library would be good.

Comment: strings are immutable. ``s.replace`` will not modify ``s``, instead you have to work with the result.

Comment: You should use `urllib.parse.unquote()` for this rather than `str.replace`. This isn't HTML encoding/decoding, it's URL quoting/unquoting and the difference is important.

Answer (score 3):

`replace` returns a new string. Save the new string to the old string.

```
s = s.replace(h,c)
```